# Unable To Write To Samba Home Directories

Tags: 11.10, permissions, samba, share, home-directory

So I have samba setup and running on my Ubuntu box. I've successfully logged in on my WinXP machine, and was able to browse my home directories but an unable to create files, folders, etc. No write access.

In my samba config, I have set the this line `read only = no`, thus granting access to write to my home directories. Restarted samba in terminal using `sudo restart smbd` and no such luck.

Is there somewhere else I need to enable write access? I also added `create mask = 0775` and `directory mask = 0775` but I'm not too sure what that is doing.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**
I created a test share and was able to write to the share. My test share is `/home/username/Pictures` But when trying to write from the home directories, access denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems like the `create mask = 0775` and `directory mask = 0775` was causing the problem. I'm not familiar with the permissions and exactly what they do but I ended up fixing it by commenting out those lines.

Comment: this link may help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions